# Nihbernate and MySql: Failed to find or load the registered .Net Framework Data Provider

Tags: .net, mysql, nhibernate, hosting

my website works locally(the solution is local the db is mysql db from my hosting company).

I now uploaded my code to my hosting company and when I try to run the project I get this error

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Failed to find or load the registered .Net Framework Data Provider.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Failed to find or load the registered .Net Framework Data Provider.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:


[ConfigurationErrorsException: Failed to find or load the registered .Net Framework Data Provider.]
   System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(DataRow providerRow) +1420114
   System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(String providerInvariantName) +88
   NHibernate.Driver.ReflectionBasedDriver..ctor(String providerInvariantName, String driverAssemblyName, String connectionTypeName, String commandTypeName) +130
   NHibernate.Driver.MySqlDataDriver..ctor() +29

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache) +98
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache) +241
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +69
   NHibernate.Bytecode.ActivatorObjectsFactory.CreateInstance(Type type) +8
   NHibernate.Connection.ConnectionProvider.ConfigureDriver(IDictionary`2 settings) +127

[HibernateException: Could not create the driver from NHibernate.Driver.MySqlDataDriver, NHibernate, Version=3.3.1.4000, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4.]
   NHibernate.Connection.ConnectionProvider.ConfigureDriver(IDictionary`2 settings) +241
   NHibernate.Connection.ConnectionProvider.Configure(IDictionary`2 settings) +86
   NHibernate.Connection.ConnectionProviderFactory.NewConnectionProvider(IDictionary`2 settings) +351
   NHibernate.Cfg.SettingsFactory.BuildSettings(IDictionary`2 properties) +1005
   NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.BuildSettings() +29
   NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.BuildSessionFactory() +44
   FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfiguration.BuildSessionFactory() +49

[FluentConfigurationException: An invalid or incomplete configuration was used while creating a SessionFactory. Check PotentialReasons collection, and InnerException for more detail.

]
   FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfiguration.BuildSessionFactory() +69
   PTBurner.Models.Nhibernate.NhibernateSessionFactory.GetSessionFactory() in NhibernateSessionFactory.cs:19
   PTBurner.Models.Nhibernate.NhibernateSessionFactoryProvider.CreateInstance(IContext context) in NhibernateSessionFactoryProvider.cs:11
   Ninject.Activation.Provider`1.Create(IContext context) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Activation\Provider.cs:38
   Ninject.Activation.Context.Resolve() in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Activation\Context.cs:157
   Ninject.<>c__DisplayClass10.<Resolve>b__c(IBinding binding) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\KernelBase.cs:386
   System.Linq.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext() +151
   System.Linq.<CastIterator>d__b1`1.MoveNext() +92
   System.Linq.Enumerable.Single(IEnumerable`1 source) +196
   Ninject.ResolutionExtensions.Get(IResolutionRoot root, IParameter[] parameters) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Syntax\ResolutionExtensions.cs:37
   PTBurner.Models.Ninject.NhibernateModule.<Load>b__0(IContext context) in Ninject\NhibernateModule.cs:15
   Ninject.Activation.Providers.CallbackProvider`1.CreateInstance(IContext context) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Activation\Providers\CallbackProvider.cs:45
   Ninject.Activation.Provider`1.Create(IContext context) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Activation\Provider.cs:38
   Ninject.Activation.Context.Resolve() in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Activation\Context.cs:157
   Ninject.<>c__DisplayClass10.<Resolve>b__c(IBinding binding) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\KernelBase.cs:386
   System.Linq.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext() +151
   System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault(IEnumerable`1 source) +4222421
   Ninject.Planning.Targets.Target`1.GetValue(Type service, IContext parent) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Planning\Targets\Target.cs:197
   Ninject.Planning.Targets.Target`1.ResolveWithin(IContext parent) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Planning\Targets\Target.cs:165
   Ninject.Activation.Providers.StandardProvider.GetValue(IContext context, ITarget target) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Activation\Providers\StandardProvider.cs:114
   Ninject.Activation.Providers.<>c__DisplayClass4.<Create>b__2(ITarget target) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Activation\Providers\StandardProvider.cs:96
   System.Linq.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext() +85
   System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source) +217
   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray(IEnumerable`1 source) +78
   Ninject.Activation.Providers.StandardProvider.Create(IContext context) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Activation\Providers\StandardProvider.cs:96
   Ninject.Activation.Context.Resolve() in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Activation\Context.cs:157
   Ninject.<>c__DisplayClass10.<Resolve>b__c(IBinding binding) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\KernelBase.cs:386
   System.Linq.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext() +151
   System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault(IEnumerable`1 source) +4222421
   Ninject.Planning.Targets.Target`1.GetValue(Type service, IContext parent) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Planning\Targets\Target.cs:197
   Ninject.Planning.Targets.Target`1.ResolveWithin(IContext parent) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Planning\Targets\Target.cs:165
   Ninject.Activation.Providers.StandardProvider.GetValue(IContext context, ITarget target) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Activation\Providers\StandardProvider.cs:114
   Ninject.Activation.Providers.<>c__DisplayClass4.<Create>b__2(ITarget target) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Activation\Providers\StandardProvider.cs:96
   System.Linq.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext() +85
   System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source) +217
   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray(IEnumerable`1 source) +78
   Ninject.Activation.Providers.StandardProvider.Create(IContext context) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Activation\Providers\StandardProvider.cs:96
   Ninject.Activation.Context.Resolve() in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Activation\Context.cs:157
   Ninject.<>c__DisplayClass10.<Resolve>b__c(IBinding binding) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\KernelBase.cs:386
   System.Linq.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext() +151
   System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault(IEnumerable`1 source) +4222421
   Ninject.Web.Mvc.NinjectDependencyResolver.GetService(Type serviceType) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject.web.mvc\mvc3\src\Ninject.Web.Mvc\NinjectDependencyResolver.cs:56
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +51

[InvalidOperationException: An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'PTBurner.Controllers.HomeController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.]
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +182
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +80
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName) +74
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory) +232
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass6.<BeginProcessRequest>b__2() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassb`1.<ProcessInApplicationTrust>b__a() +13
   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.<GetCallInAppTrustThunk>b__0(Action f) +7
   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Action action) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Func`1 func) +124
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +98
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +50
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +16
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +8970356
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +184
```

The mysql version is 5.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you installed the Mysql ADO.Net provider locally which includes it in the GAC (Global Assembly Cache). Your hoster haven't done this. The easiest way to solve it is to include the Mysql ADO.Net provider dll in the bin folder of your project.

Comment: Where do I get this .dll from?

Comment: I think I found it. I downloaded  5.1.7 as that is what my hosting company is using and I was not sure if the latest version would have worked. I also had to add this line to fluent         .ExposeConfiguration(c => c.Properties.Add("hbm2ddl.keywords", "none")) as it then came up with a reserved word error. I hope it does not have any adverse effects. I found this a bit more harder than when using mssql 2008 and nihbernate(would have thought the otherway around)

Comment: mssql ADO.NET provider is integrated into .NET Base Class Library that's why it is easier. `"hbm2ddl.keywords", "none"` means that NHibernate should not try to escape Keywords when used as table or column names. If you haven't used keywords as names this should not be a problem

Comment: I don't think I used keywords for tables or columns. But I am not sure how to check though. Do you think I could have used the newest provider or should I stick with the version my hosting company uses?

Comment: IMO the one the hoster uses is enough. Best way to know is try and see